# django nginx gunicorn config needs to work on ip:port

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

I have currently config nginx gunicorn everything is working fine i am building a rest api the django should work something like this ip:port but instead if i enter the IP address in the browser the django application is working there is no port used how to change it to run on a specified port.

Answer (score 0):

your nginx use port 80 by default

Port 80 is the port number assigned to commonly used internet communication protocol, Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP). It is the port from which a computer sends and receives Web client-based communication and messages from a Web server and is used to send and receive HTML pages or data.

Answer (score 0):

You can run gunicorn specifying the port. In the example below 8000. And then point nginx to it.

`gunicorn application_module --bind=0.0.0.0:8000`